# Does Vue-Konva support GLSL?

Tags: vue.js, glsl, konvajs

Currently I'm using Vue-Konva.js to help me build a 2d editor for panorama.

Does konva.js support GLSL code for apply image effect (ex: stereographic projection)?

Maybe like this format.

KonvaScens.vue

```
<template>
  <v-stage :config="configKonva">
    <v-layer>
      <v-image :config="configImage"></v-image>
    </v-layer>
  </v-stage>
</template>
<script>
import {myVertexShader, myFragmentShader} from 'imageShader'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      testImg: new Image(100, 100),
      configKonva: {
        width: 500,
        height: 500
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    configImage () {
      return {
        x: 20,
        y: 20,
        image: this.testImg,
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        vertexShader: myVertexShader,
        fragmentShader: myFragmentShader
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.testImg.src = "https://konvajs.github.io/assets/lion.png"
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `vue-konva` doesn't support GLSL. GLSL can be used in `webgl` canvas context. But `Konva` uses only 2d context.